# Ionic V1 Side Menu Content strange behaviour

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, right-to-left

I am Working on a Ionic 1 project which have two language Arabic which is RTL and English which is LTR.

I added two menus to handle this, one with `side="right"` for Arabic and the other one with `side="left"` for English

Every thing is working fine at start but when I change the language the side menu content is draggable to the left and right !!

It should be draggable only to left only when then left menu is displayed and to right only when the right menu is displayed

**Trials**

I tried with `drag-content='false'`  [disable both directions].

I trired to add event Listener on `ionic-side-menus-content` on drag to check if direction is left so I could `preventDefault` and `return false;` [didn't worked]

here is screenshot of the issue.

**Accepted Direction**

[image: Accepted Direction]

**Wrong behaviour**

[image: Wrong behaviour]

**app.html code**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
<!-- Left menu -->
<ion-side-menu side="left" ng-if="$root.lang=='en'">
 <div ng-include="'tpls/side-menu.html'"></div>
</ion-side-menu>
<ion-side-menu side="right" ng-if="$root.lang=='ar'">
 <div ng-include="'tpls/side-menu.html'"></div>
</ion-side-menu>

<ion-side-menu-content>
<!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
 <ion-nav-bar align-title="center">
 <ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-back-button>

<ion-nav-buttons side="{{$root.lang=='ar'?'right':'left'}}">
  <button class="button button-icon button-clear  ion-navicon" menu-toggle="{{$root.lang=='ar'?'right':'left'}}">
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<div class="bar bar-subheader">
  <div class="searchBox primaryColor-bg">
    <div class="ionicons">
      <i class="ion-camera"></i>
      <span>|</span>
      <i class="ion-search"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="{{'TITLES.SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER'|translate}}" value="">
    </div>
    </div>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" >

  </ion-nav-view>

  </ion-side-menu-content>


 </ion-side-menus>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can always create two side menus and show each one of them depending on the language in a `ng-if` directive.

Comment: I already have two side menus as you can see from code but within one `ion-side-menus-content`

Comment: [rtl] tag is for register-transfer-level.